# How to debug cross-compiled QEMU program with GDB?

Tags: gdb, qemu, riscv

I'm having trouble debugging a simple program running in QEMU with GDB.  GDB seems unable to find where I am in the program (in that it always displays `??` as my current location), and it never hits any breakpoint I set.

In one terminal, I run QEMU:

```
$ cat add.c
int main() {
    int x = 9;
    int v = 1;
    while (1) {
        int q = x + v;
    }
    return 0;
}

$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc add.c -g
$ qemu-system-riscv64 -gdb tcp::1234 -drive file=a.out,format=raw
```

And in another terminal, I run GDB:

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2.90.20190228-git
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0 --target=riscv64-unknown-elf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) target remote :1234
Remote debugging using :1234
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) list
1       int main() {
2           int x = 9;
3           int v = 1;
4           while (1) {
5               int q = x + v;
6           }
7           return 0;
8       }
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1018e: file add.c, line 2.
(gdb) b 5
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1019a: file add.c, line 5.
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 3 at 0x10114
(gdb) b 4
Breakpoint 4 at 0x101a8: file add.c, line 4.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

I never hit a breakpoint, even though the program should be looping infinitely.  It seems odd that it's displaying `0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`...but maybe that's okay?

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I step through this program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing a linker script and some startup code - disclaimer: I am a newcomer to riscv.
You will find a lot of information on those two topics on the Internet, but  you basically need to specify where your program will be located in RAM, to establish a stack and initialize the frame pointer:
This is required if you want to be able to call functions and declare automatic C variables like a, b, c in your program.

I used the Windows [toolchain](https://github.com/kendryte/kendryte-gnu-toolchain/releases/download/v8.2.0-20190213/kendryte-toolchain-win-amd64-8.2.0-20190213.zip) from Kendryte for the purpose of this example (the Linux version is available [here](https://github.com/kendryte/kendryte-gnu-toolchain/releases/download/v8.2.0-20190213/kendryte-toolchain-ubuntu-amd64-8.2.0-20190213.tar.gz)), and a Windows version of qemu retrieved [here](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/qemu-w64-setup-20190218.exe).

1) Linker script: the example uses a slightly modified example of the default linker script used by riscv64-unknown-elf-ld:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld --verbose > riscv64-virt.ld
```

Edit riscv64-virt.ld, and keep only the lines delimited by:

```
==================================================
```

Add a description for the memory layout of the qemu-system-riscv64 virt machine:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH(riscv)
MEMORY
{
/* qemu-system-risc64 virt machine */
   RAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 128M 
}
ENTRY(_start)
```

Use `ORIGIN(RAM)` and `LENGTH(RAM)` instead of hard-coded values, and provide a `__stack_top` symbol:

```
 PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(RAM))); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(RAM)) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
 PROVIDE(__stack_top = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM));
```

By the way, there are multiple ways of learning the memory layout of a qemu-system target machine, but I usually look at its Device Tree file:

```
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -machine dumpdtb=riscv64-virt.dtb
dtc -I dtb -O dts -o riscv-virt.dts riscv-virt.dtb
```

The section describing the memory tells us it starts at 0x80000000:

```
memory@80000000 {
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x8000000>;
};
```

riscv64-virt.ld:

```
/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-littleriscv", "elf64-littleriscv",
          "elf64-littleriscv")
OUTPUT_ARCH(riscv)
MEMORY
{
/* qemu-system-risc64 virt machine */
   RAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 128M 
}
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(RAM))); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(RAM)) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  PROVIDE(__stack_top = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM));
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.sdata .rela.sdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.s.*)
      *(.rela.sbss .rela.sbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.sb.*)
      *(.rela.sdata2 .rela.sdata2.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.s2.*)
      *(.rela.sbss2 .rela.sbss2.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.sb2.*)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) }
  .iplt           : { *(.iplt) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .sdata2         :
  {
    *(.sdata2 .sdata2.* .gnu.linkonce.s2.*)
  }
  .sbss2          : { *(.sbss2 .sbss2.* .gnu.linkonce.sb2.*) }
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      :
   {
     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__tdata_start = .);
     *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*)
   }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (0, .);
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  .got            : { *(.got.plt) *(.igot.plt) *(.got) *(.igot) }
  /* We want the small data sections together, so single-instruction offsets
     can access them all, and initialized data all before uninitialized, so
     we can shorten the on-disk segment size.  */
  .sdata          :
  {
    __global_pointer$ = . + 0x800;
    *(.srodata.cst16) *(.srodata.cst8) *(.srodata.cst4) *(.srodata.cst2) *(.srodata .srodata.*)
    *(.sdata .sdata.* .gnu.linkonce.s.*)
  }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .sbss           :
  {
    *(.dynsbss)
    *(.sbss .sbss.* .gnu.linkonce.sb.*)
    *(.scommon)
  }
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .debug_addr     0 : { *(.debug_addr) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}
```

2) startup.s: (credits: [here](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/arch/riscv/programmer) and [here](https://github.com/rust-embedded/riscv-rt/blob/master/asm.S)).

```
.section .init, "ax"
.global _start
_start:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_undefined ra
    .option push
    .option norelax
    la gp, __global_pointer$
    .option pop
    la sp, __stack_top
    add s0, sp, zero
    jal zero, main
    .cfi_endproc
    .end
```

add.c: (your code)

```
int main() {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 12;
    while (1) {
        int c = a + b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

3) compiling/linking, and creating a listing:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -O0 -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -Wl,-T,riscv64-virt.ld -o add.elf startup.s add.c
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -D  add.elf > add.objdump
```

4) starting qemu in a console:

```
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -m 128M -gdb tcp::1234,ipv4  -kernel add.elf
```

I am not sure that the qemu options you were using: `-drive file=a.out,format=raw` 
are correct, and I think they are not, but I did not spend time checking, and used the options I am usually using: `-kernel add.elf`

4) starting gdb in another console (I am using here a GDB I compiled with TUI support for mingw64 for my own convenience).

```
riscv64-elf-gdb --tui  add.elf
```

[image]

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
main () at add.c:5
(gdb) p a
$1 = 4
(gdb) p b
$2 = 12
(gdb) p c
$3 = 16
(gdb)
```

This may have been a little bit long, but I hope this will help.
Please note that the startup code is good enough for your code, but some important initializations are missing, such as copying the data section from flash to RAM (not relevant here), and clearing the .bss section.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  However, I tried your suggestion and am still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: I restored my first, long answer, since the example was working. I will answer any aditionnal questions if needed (and if I can..). I took a guess with the second answer, since I don't have the toolchain you are using and your compilation command was failing in my case - My mistake.

Comment: Just saw your new, longer answer - thanks for the detail.  I will work through it tomorrow and report back with the results.  If it's at all useful, the toolchain I'm using is a prebuilt one from here: https://www.sifive.com/boards

Comment: Building/debugging using the SiFive toolchain worked fine as well.

Comment: thanks for this great answer.  Follow up question: why don't I have to do any of this when running programs under "normal" circumstances, e.g. running with an OS on my laptop?  GCC appears to link with a set of default `crt`s and linker file(s), which presumably set up the stack and set the `__executable_start`.  Do these default runtimes expect the presence of an OS to help out?  If so, how exactly does that work?

Comment: I would say that each gcc compiler is tightly coupled to a specific combination of target CPU, target operating system (or bare-metal environment), a specific standard C library.  If you execute `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -dumpmachine`, the output will be `riscv64-unknown-elf` (unknown means no specific operating system is being targeted). On my Linux x86_64 PC, it would be `x86_64-linux-gnu`, and on my 32-bits ARM system, it would be `arm-linux-gnueabihf`-  look for gcc 'triplets' on the Internet. Example of C libraries would be glibc, musl for Linux, newlib for bare-metal system.

Comment: Thus the gcc/glibc/linker combinaion on your laptop are already tuned for creating executable files as expected/required by the operating system it is targeting, as you were suspecting.

Comment: Frant, another follow-up question, if your patience with me hasn't already run out :).  

Where did you get `LENGTH = 256M`?  According to this `reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x8000000>;`, the length as I understand it is `0x8000000`, which is 128Mebibytes, not 256.  Did I calculate incorrectly?

Comment: @twico You are perfectly right, the 256M are a copy/paste error from the linker scripts/qemu commands  I am usually using with the aarch64  qemu-virt  machine: `reg = <0x0 0x40000000 0x0 0x10000000>;` I fixed the errors above - thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a great answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using `riscv-gnu-toolchain` built with `glibc` is a much simpler method to debug riscv programs unless you are debugging some system-level program where you must use `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` instead of `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc`. For a simple program like your `add.c`, using user-space `qemu-riscv` and glibc `riscv-gnu-toolchain` can save you a lot of trouble. (One can install these tools following the commands listed at the bottom)

---

By the time I am writing this answer, there are two different versions of the riscv toolchain: one built with `newlib` which provides `riscv64-unknown-elf-*` and another with `glibc` which provides `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-*`. There are also two versions of qemu: `qemu-system-riscv64` for debugging kernels or bare-metal programs and `qemu-riscv64` for debugging user-space programs compiled with libc.

For simple programs like `add.c`, one may debug it with the second type of the toolchain:

- Compile: `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc add.c -o add -g`
- Run: `qemu-riscv64 -L /opt/riscv/sysroot/ -g 1234 add -S`
- Then launch GDB: `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gdb add`

  Inside GDB:

  - `target remote:1234`
  - `b main`
  - `c`

And the program should break at the main entrance.

(Another option is to statically link the program: `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc add.c -o add -g -static` and then `qemu-riscv64 -g 1234 add -S` should work as well)

---

I did not find many documents mentioning user-space riscv qemu. All I found were articles talking about how to use qemu to debug OS kernels with RISC-V ISA. For the convenience of other newcomers to riscv like me, I will show in the following how to build the mentioned tools.

- qemu (https://www.qemu.org/download/#source)

```
wget https://download.qemu.org/qemu-5.0.0.tar.xz
tar xvJf qemu-5.0.0.tar.xz
cd qemu-5.0.0 # higher versions might have problems
./configure --target-list=riscv64-linux-user,riscv64-softmmu
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

, where `riscv64-softmmu` gives you `qemu-system-riscv64` and `riscv64-linux-user` gives you `qemu-riscv64`.

- riscv-gnu-toolchain (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain.git)

```
git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain.git
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autotools-dev curl python3 libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev libgmp-dev gawk build-essential bison flex texinfo gperf libtool patchutils bc zlib1g-dev libexpat-dev libncurses5-dev
./configure --prefix=/opt/riscv --enable-multilib
sudo make linux # this provides you the glibc set of tools (the ones we need here)
sudo make # this provides you the newlib set of tools
```