# Does the stack in this 'ld' linker script overwrite the stored executable?

Tags: gnu, ld, riscv

I have a question about the behavior of the linker script found in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193198/2421349

To save you a click, the relavant portion is:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH(riscv)
MEMORY
{
   /* qemu-system-risc64 virt machine */
   RAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 128M 
}
ENTRY(_start)
```

And in a later section:

```
 PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(RAM)));
 . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(RAM)) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
 PROVIDE(__stack_top = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM));
```

We set `__executable_start` to begin at `ORIGIN(RAM)`.  Then we use the `.` command to move the linker output location `SIZEOF_HEADERS` bytes forward.  And finally we set `__stack_top = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM)`.

Assuming the stack grows down towards `ORIGIN(RAM)`, won't it eventually overwrite `__executable_start` and whatever `SIZEOF_HEADERS` is if the stack grows large enough?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the stack grows large enough, it will eventually start overwriting parts of the memory it should not. But this is not specific to this linker script: Ultimately, the memory is a finite resource, and any stack growing too much because too large automatic variables beeing allocated, and/or out of control recursive calls will end up causing problems.